# MVVM - Select item in ListBox with Double click and make bold

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I want to make it so a double click is required to select an item in a ListBox. This selected item should always be bold. I know the **SelectedItem** property will no longer reflect the item I am treating as the selected item, so the XAML below that I was previously using to make the selected item bold will no longer work.

```
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

I have looked into how to handle a double click with MVVM and have concluded that it is ok to use code behind and the MouseDoubleClick event.

```
private void lbProfiles_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    _viewModel.SelectedProfile = ((ListBox)sender.)SelectedItem as MyProfile;
    //What should go here?
}
```

My view model will have a **SelectedProfile** property that I think will be set in the method above. Is there anyway to bind **SelectedProfile** in XAML or will it have to be managed in the code behind?  Also, what is the best way to make this item bold?

---

**Edit 1:**

I ended up tweaking Rachel's answer a little so that on a single click the item is highlighted but not selected. That way the view model can have a SelectedItem property and a HighlightedItem property.

```
private void ListBoxItem_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ClickCount < 2)
        e.Handled = true;

    var clickedItem = ((ContentPresenter)e.Source).Content as MyProfile;

    if (clickedItem != null)
    {
        //Let view model know a new item was clicked but not selected.
        _modelView.HighlightedProfile = clickedItem;

        foreach (var item in lbProfiles.Items)
        {
            ListBoxItem lbi = 
                lbProfiles.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item) as ListBoxItem;

            //If item is not displayed on screen it may not have been created yet.
            if (lbi != null)
            {
                if (item == clickedItem)
                {
                    lbi.Background = SystemColors.ControlLightBrush;
                }
                else
                {

                    lbi.Background = lbProfiles.Background;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to select an item on `DoubleClick` only is to mark the click event as `Handled` if the [ClickCount](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mousebuttoneventargs.clickcount.aspx) is less than 2

This would also allow you to keep your `Trigger` that sets the text as `Bold` when it's selected

```
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
        <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseDown" Handler="ListBoxItem_PreviewMouseDown" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>


private void ListBoxItem_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ClickCount < 2)
        e.Handled = true;
}
```

Just keep in mind that this disables all single click events on the `ListBoxItem`. If you want to allow some single-click events, you'll have to adjust the `PreviewMouseDown` event to not mark specific clicks as `Handled`.